# registerForRemoteNotifications is not working after calling unregisterForRemoteNotifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

is not working after calling

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

any idea why?
official document commented that:Apps unregistered through this method can always re-register.

Comment: This has been true and not a problem up to iOS 9. Are you testing on an iOS 10 device?

Answer (score 0):

You should just Uninstall the app and delete that code!

Also do not unregister the remote notifications. This is obviously not a good way to do.So revue this line :-

**[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications]**

It puts the app in an unstable state where calling registerForRemoteNotifications no longer works.

All you have to call it once in your code.

**[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications]**

Comment: the scenario is like this: we provide APNS in our app, and we want to have a function that can let users to turn off the push if desired. and use can turn on it back again if users want to. Looks like we have to implement this function on our server side, and [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications] is not a option.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like there is the similar [question](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/63038) on Apple Developer Forum.
And it has an answer.

Comment: Link needs updating here